# Where is the Facebook Status feed URL these days?

Tags: facebook, feed, status

I know that it was previously possible to display your most recent Facebook statuses on your website as an RSS feed, but it seems they've changed their setup and I can't figure out where to find the feed anymore....

I saw some people searching for this a while ago, but since Facebook just released their new layout, I didn't know if this might have changed again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should this be on super user?

Comment: @Dolph: I'd say nope, FB API-related question.

Comment: This is the right place for your question: http://superuser.com/

Comment: @MassimoF - These types of questions are being closed on superuser.com about facebook api and such, for example, http://superuser.com/questions/105618/how-to-set-facebook-to-update-twitter-but-twitter-posts-to-not-update-facebook-c The question is programming related or at least has programming-related answers. It can belong here.

Comment: @Chris Schmitz: Do you want to display only your own status updates, or those of your friends? Or, do you want to display statuses of the current facebook user visiting the website, or your own status updates all the time? It makes a difference as to what mechanism is used.

Comment: @jdk: I would only like to display my own status updates.  I just want to display the single most recent update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this for a feed in JSON-format.

http://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/feed

Comment: For more details on this checkout http://itslennysfault.com/easiest-way-to-get-the-latest-status-from-facebook-fan-pages-in-php

Comment: They have updated their api.  Now, "An access token is required to request this resource."

Answer (score 3):

Facebook appears to have killed all the public status feeds in the name of user privacy.  The only way to fetch it is to build a facebook application that gets your status updates, and then associating your facebook account with that application to give it permission to access your status updates so it can put them somewhere else.

Thankfully, [someone has already done that](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=301182998268) for us.  Just go to http://apps.facebook.com/statusexport/ while logged in to facebook and grant the app permission.  Then it will give you a public URL to an RSS feed of your status updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple... This is an easy way to load your latest status(es) using graph.facebook.com through curl / php. Includes a quick simple function.

[Easiest way to load your latest facebook status](http://itslennysfault.com/easiest-way-to-get-the-latest-status-from-facebook-fan-pages-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to display status updates only, you can use:

[https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/posts](https://graph.facebook.com/%5Buid%5D/posts)

This URL will return a JSON string of user [uid]:s status updates.

Answer (score 1):

I found this site which you authenticate, and it will then give you a working rss feed.
I have found that it does have some limitations, but you can see it here:
http://www.fbrss.com

Answer (score 0):

To get your status feed, follow these instructions:

1. Log into Facebook
2. Go to http://www.facebook.com/notifications.php
3. Click the link titled "Your Notifications" at the bottom of the box to the right of the list of notifications
4. That will bring you to a feed of your notifications, which is not what you asked for.  This url will be something like feed://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=XXXXXX&viewer= XXXXXX&key=YYYYYYYY&format=rss20
5. Change `notifications.php` to `status.php` in the URL (preserving all the URL parameters).
6. That should be a feed of your status updates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I tried this out and got the following error: "This feed URL is no longer valid. Visit this page to find the new URL, if you have access, http://www.facebook.com/minifeed.php?status&id=...." -- Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  It worked for me.  Did you get that error in the browser that you used to log into facebook?  (I did, so its possible that it only works if you are logged in.)

Comment: Yeah, I was in the same browser that I was logged in to Facebook with....  I tried it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Well, I don't know then.  I tried it in Firefox and Safari, and didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Start at http://www.facebook.com/notes.php and click on the "My Friend's Notes" link. Change the `friends_notes` part of the url to `friends_status`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't clarify... I need the feed for just my own status updates.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

### Programmatically specifying user to query status updates for

***(Note: This is a server-side solution)***

It's possible the feed you're looking for has been deprecated for security purposes.

Alternatively **[facebook FQL on the `Status`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status_(FQL)) table** might provide an answer because it allows you to specify the user ID (for example, your own) for which to retrieve status updates, and a time frame can be specified to limit them as desired.

A raw fb FQL query example,  for status updates:

```
select uid,status_id,message 
from status 
where uid in 
    (select uid2 from friend where uid1= uid) 
    AND time > {time in the last week}
```

The main [FQL guide starts here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL).

### Sample

Poking around the Internet you can pick up sample code of FQL code being called from **PHP** and other platforms.

PHP example:

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='$id'";
$query = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($q);
?>
```

The [facebook client API library](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Client_Libraries) for your platform of choice can be downloaded and used to issue FQL statements.

--

There is also a [Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php) hosted online for facebook developers to test API statements against their own account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a RSS feed generator for your Facebook Statuses (or Photos) like the [RSS Feeds](http://apps.facebook.com/rss-feeds/) application on Facebook.
It will help you generate a RSS feed for all your statuses and photos while maintaining the privacy modes.
Although, I am not a fan of the user interface the application has, but the functionality is what is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Theres also anther way to do it..Which is simple and easy...its not an rss feed but a plugin can be developed to output as an rss...Theres a tutorial of it on [http://Fourgefeed.com](http://fourgefeed.com)